# How can i search fetch all data from 3 tables and show it in my view in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables School,School details, and admission , and i am saving school id of school in school details & admission table with other information. Now i want to get all schools list that i am saving in all 3 tables. I am able to find data of two table school and admission not of school details table.

```
public function schoolslist($class='', $city='')
{
    $schools = Admission::whereHas('school', function($query) use($city) { 
        $query->where('city', 'like', $city);})
           ->where('admission_classes', $class)
           ->where('status', '1')
           ->orderBy('id','desc')
           ->paginate(10);

    return view('frontend.schoollist',compact('schools'));
}
```

Comment: are you using laravel's relationship?

Comment: yes sir,   public function School()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School','school_id');
    }
    public function SchoolDetails()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SchoolDetails','school_id');
    }

Answer (score 0):

try adding `with`:

```
public function schoolslist($class='', $city='')
{
    $schools = Admission::whereHas('school', function($query) use($city) { 
        $query->where('city', 'like', $city);})
          ->with('SchoolDetails')
          ->where('admission_classes', $class)
          ->where('status', '1')
          ->orderBy('id','desc')
          ->paginate(10);

    return view('frontend.schoollist',compact('schools'));
}
```

Comment: @foreach($schools as $i => $school) {{ $school->School['school_name']}} {{ $school->admission_classes]}}   {{$school->SchoolDetails['slug']}} @endforeach , i am getting data of school table, admission table but not of schooldetails table please help

Comment: Help me sir..please